# iOS - UILocalNotification - can schedule only up to 64 slots at a given time

Tags: ios, push-notification, uilocalnotification

**Overview**

- I have an iOS app which sends local notifications at specific dates.
- I just learned that I can only schedule 64 notifications at a given time.
- There are cases when I can't schedule notifications as the 64 slots are filled.
- So I store them in the database and when the user responds to a notification I check if there are any available slots and schedule the remaining notifications.

**Problem**

- When the user doesn't  respond to a notification my code is not executed so I am not able to schedule the remaining notifications.

**Question**

1. Is there a solution for this problem ?
2. can I execute a piece of code (house keeping) at certain times ?
3. is there any work around for this ?

Comment: Not sure if you still need this. How about managing the scheduledNotifications array? So you can check when there is actually room in that array. Or you could empty the first item in the array when it becomes full and have your application still flag it as something that needs to be followed up on.

Comment: thanks Micheal, you are rite I can check if there is room in the array and then schedule any pending notifications. But I can do that ONLY when the app is open. So if the user doesn't decide to open the app, I wouldn't able to check if there is room.

Comment: The best I could think of is, create a database and store all the pending notifications. When the user opens the app, the app would check when ever possible (after delete / after notification is fired) if it can schedule some pending notifications. Again when the app is not open, nothing much can be done. Also need to carefully check if you can schedule the notification before creating an entry otherwise it is best to tell the user, that he might need to open the app every time the notification is fired, so that you when the notification is fired and the app is opened to execute your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may not want to signal to the user there is a problem, but rather just do it in the background. If a user has 64 notifications for one app and hasn't opened the app, then they probably aren't using the app. Once a notification has fired it isn't in the array anymore. So you will have room every time a notification is fired off. They do however remain in notification centre, which you have to clear out yourself.

Its usually better to not present possible problems to the user, but rather handle them in a way that makes sense internally if that is an option. Look up the delegate methods for the appDelegate and you will most likely find ways you can handle what you are trying to do.

Thought I would make a post in case you wanted to accept the answer.

Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks Michael for that tip, yeah I suppose what you said makes sense, if the user doesn't open the app then it probably means he is isn't using it anymore. When a non-repeat notification is fired automatically it is removed off the [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications], so I think it not required to manually clear them. I try to schedule any pending notifications when slots are available.